# Visual Studio Code C# (MacBook Pro Apple M1) Debug not working

Tags: c#, .net

After moving from my old Macbook to the Apple M1 chip the Debug feature hasn't been working as error listed below. The application runs fine without debugging. Any ideas or faced same issue please?

```
../.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.7/.debugger/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode --connection=/var/folders/hc/z2qjkly53130z2_ty2gb09jc0000gn/T/CoreFxPipe_vsdbg-ui-40ec4fc1eee944929c2ec13b202139a6 
Stack overflow.
   at System.Collections.HashHelpers.GetPrime(Int32)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Initialize(Int32)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]..ctor(Int32, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.AppContext.Setup(Char**, Char**, Int32)
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with Visual Studio Code, but rather .NET. Others are having the same issues: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/12/11/net-development-on-apple-silicon/

Comment: Many thanks @Jacob, you're correct! Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are new insider build which supports M1 Mac with ARM64 options from here [visual studio insider build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)